# How to release memory occupied by a scedule selector?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

A selector have been scheduled to the frame rate, `[self schedule:@selector(tick:)];` and it keep executing all time (since application run). thus it keep increasing the memory, that leads to degradation in performance. So can we keep releasing the memory while excuting the selector.

Comment: If you have a framerate-synced scheduler, you should use scheduleUpdate instead, it's faster and uses less memory. But like @Johnmph said, your problem is most likely elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schedule will only call the selector at frame rate interval, no memory is taken by this operation.

If you have memory which increases, maybe it's because you have memory leak in your code inside the tick: method.

And no autoreleasepool is required because schedule lets the autorelease pool managed by the run loop to release autoreleased objects.